# Faint Lines with Subdivision Modifier

Tags: modeling, rendering, subdivision-surface

Any idea why this object isn't smooth at 3 subdivision levels?

[image: Faint Lines with Subdivision Modifier]

Comment: hi, did you activate the smooth shading on your object ?
Or is there any issue with you normals orientations ?

Comment: do you mean viewport shading? this image is actually a cycles render. I'm wondering if this could be a Phong tag issue. this model came from C4D as an imported obj. In C4D, i saw a similar issue and when I changed the phong angle from 22 to 40, id fixed it. do you know how to access the phong setting in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Following the previous comments, I would suggest to try the following :

- Select the object in object mode
- In the header menu, go to Object -> Shade Smooth
- Try to adjust the normal smoothing by going into the properties panel, in the object data properties, and enable the auto smooth + try increase the default value

[image]

Comment: i will try that. thank you very much for the suggestion!

Comment: so this is interesting - Auto Smooth was already selected and set at 30. I adjusted the value 0-100 to no avail. I deselected it and that did the trick! lines are gone now. Is that odd?

Comment: It is really strange yes. Maybe a simple recompute of all normals could have done the job too ..

Comment: well, thank you for responding. much appreciated.